# Picasso could load image from my localhost

Tags: android, picasso

when i try to open image on my local web server, that can be show without any problem, not i'm trying to load that with `Picasso` on android application, i set internet permission and application can be get data from network

my image path on local web server:

```
localhost/public/channels/7BYtHhP5LP8.png
```

and my network ip address:

```
192.168.1.4
```

this my code to load image:

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load("192.168.1.4/public/channels/7BYtHhP5LP8.png")
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
        .into(holder.imageAvatar, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                holder.loading_avatar_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.imageAvatar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load("192.168.1.4/public/channels/7BYtHhP5LP8.png")
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.cafe_alachiq_place_holder_logo)
                        .error(R.drawable.cafe_alachiq_logo)
                        .into(holder.imageAvatar, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                holder.loading_avatar_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.imageAvatar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                holder.loading_avatar_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.imageAvatar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.imageAvatar.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cafe_alachiq_logo));
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
```

in this picasso implamentation latest `public void onError()` work for me

Answer (score 0):

Use URI with scheme "http://192.168.1.4/public/channels/7BYtHhP5LP8.png". Also check if the image is visible just by typing the URI into the browser (from phone).

You'll also need to change network policy:

```
.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
```

Because OFFLINE means ([documentation](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/NetworkPolicy.html))

> OFFLINE
>   Forces the request through the disk cache only, skipping network.

Comment: i'm using `.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)` for use cache when device dont have internet connection, if its possible to get online, picasso try to get again online not dish cache, its incorrect?

Comment: No, network policy "offline" means picasso will not try to download an image from network. It will only check if it has been cached before. I think you want just the default behavior so you don't have to call .networkPolicy(..) at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for over an hour now.

I did the following:

1. Retrieve local ip (mac) using `ifconfig | grep 192`. and took the value from inet.

Still it was not working because I was missing permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Added this in my AndroidManifest.xml and it works like a charm.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load("
http://10.0.3.2/public/channels/7BYtHhP5LP8.png")
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
            .into(holder.imageAvatar, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    holder.loading_avatar_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.imageAvatar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load("192.168.1.4/public/channels/7BYtHhP5LP8.png")
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.cafe_alachiq_place_holder_logo)
                            .error(R.drawable.cafe_alachiq_logo)
                            .into(holder.imageAvatar, new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                    holder.loading_avatar_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    holder.imageAvatar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onError() {
                                    holder.loading_avatar_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    holder.imageAvatar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    holder.imageAvatar.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cafe_alachiq_logo));
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
```

Try with this IP. It might work for you.